# Python: Error retrieving and modifying values in a dictionary using .append()?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, append

Let's say I have a list of characters and I want to map each to the number of times it occurs in the list. The following code accomplishes this:

```
characters = ['a','b','c','a']
d = {}
for ch in characters:
   d[ch] = d.get(ch,0) + 1
return d
```

Now let's say, instead of having each character mapped to the number of times it occurs in the list, I want to map it to a list of 1's, where each 1 represents an occurance in the list. So for example, something like {a:[1,1], b:[1], c:[1]}. I use the same format but it doesn't work. Can someone explain why not?

```
characters = ['a','b','c','a']
d = {}
for ch in characters:
   d[ch] = d.get(ch,[]).append(1)
#print type(d['a'])
return d
```

I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append', even though a print type(d['a']) returns "list" if I remove the .append() in the for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `d[ch] = d.get(ch,[]).append(1)` sets `d[ch]` to the value returned by `append` function which is None. Do this instead:

```
d[ch] = d.get(ch, [])
d[ch].append(1)
```

Comment: @user2241856 if you find it useful please mark the answer tick.

Answer (score 2):

```
characters = ['a','b','c','a']
d = {}
for ch in characters:
   d[ch] = d.get(ch,[]).append(1)
#print type(d['a'])
return d
```

`dict.get` returns the value at the key `ch` and if it doesn't exist it returns the default value you provided,  the list `[]` you have created. Anyway, I think you may be confused because `d.get` doesn't set any values, it only returns one. Then you are appending `1` to this list. `.append` is an inplace operation so it won't return the post-appended list as you may have expected, it simply returns `None` to signify that it is not supposed to be used the way you have. What you could do instead is

```
d.setdefault(ch, []).append(1)
```

Which does what you would expect ;)
To avoid this crazy syntax you could make use of a `collections.defaultdict` like so:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
d[ch].append(1)
```

which looks much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the value of `d[ch]` to the return value of `[].append`. Think of it this way your code is the equivalent of

```
tmp = d.get(ch,[])
d[ch] = tmp.append(1)
```

Try this instead:

```
d[ch] = d.get(ch,[])
d[ch].append(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain further the difference between the two codes? For example, for the first iteration, wouldn't I obtain d['a'] = [].append(1)? This would mean d['a'] is now [1]. By the last iteration, d['a'] = d.get('a',[]).append(1). Since d['a'] is already defined, wouldn't I get d['a'] = [1].append(1), in which case I would get [1,1]? Thanks.

Comment: @user2241856 try `m = [1]; m.append(1)` at the interactive interpreter. It *doesn't* return `[1, 1]`, but `None` - the append is done by modifying `m`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposed solutions:

```
characters = ['a','b','c','a']
d = {}
for ch in characters:
    d.setdefaultappend(ch, []).append(1)
return d
```

Answer (score -1):

use python `dir` function

`list` has append method

`dist` has no append method

```
>>> characters = []
>>> d = {}
>>> dir(characters)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', 
'__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', 
'__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
'__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', 
'__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', 
'__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append',
'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']

>>> dir(d)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', 
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', 
'__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', 
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 
'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 
'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
```

Comment: Is that a different version of python? I have dir(characters) including append.

Comment: Your characters must be a `set` @Timothy, you should fix that

Comment: set characters and d variable